# PDO/MySQL fetch multiple columns with if statement

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement, pdo

I'm currently trying to fetch two images location from my database, how do I return both columns and if both empty then echo another image. This is what I've got so far.
How do I return both photo and photo_small so that I may echo them in a php file.

```
PUBLIC FUNCTION Profile_Pic($uiD) {
    $sth = $this->db->prepare("SELECT photo,photo_small FROM users WHERE uiD = :id");
    $sth->execute(array(':id' => $uiD));

        if ($sth->rowCount() > 0) {
                $data = $row['photo'];
            return $data; 
        } else {
            $data = './icons/users.png';
            return $data;
        } 
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
PUBLIC FUNCTION Profile_Pic($uiD) {
    $sql = "SELECT photo,photo_small FROM users WHERE uiD = ?";
    $sth = $this->db->prepare($sql);
    $sth->execute(array($uiD));
    $data = $sth->fetch();
    if (empty($data['photo'])) {
        $data['photo'] = './icons/users.png';
    }
    if (empty($data['photo_small'])) {
        $data['photo_small'] = './icons/users.png';
    }
    return $data;
}
```

if you want to replace **both** images if even one is absent

```
PUBLIC FUNCTION Profile_Pic($uiD) {
    $sql = "SELECT photo,photo_small FROM users WHERE uiD = ?";
    $sth = $this->db->prepare($sql);
    $sth->execute(array($uiD));
    $data = $sth->fetch();
    if (empty($data['photo']) || empty($data['photo_small'])) {
        $data['photo'] = './icons/users.png';
        $data['photo_small'] = './icons/users.png';
    }
    return $data;
}
```

Comment: Yes, works flawlessly. Thank you, I understand what you did now.

Comment: You're missing a closing parenthesis in the if statement. Overall, perfect answer.

Answer (score 0):

1. Just return all of the values you want in an array.
2. You can ensure that both `photo` and `photo_small` are not empty strings or `NULL` by using [`empty()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php).
3. Don't forget to retrieve your row using [`PDOStatement::fetch()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php).
4. You should not use `rowCount()` to determine the number of rows returned in a `SELECT` statement. According to the documentation for [`PDOStatement::rowCount()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php):

   > For most databases, PDOStatement::rowCount() does not return the number of rows affected by a SELECT statement.

Try this:

```
$row = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
if ($row && !empty($row['photo']) && !empty($row['photo_small'])) {
  $data = array('photo' => $row['photo'], 'photo_small' => $row['photo_small']);
  return $data; 
} else {
  $data = array('photo' => './icons/users.png', 'photo_small' => './icons/users.png');
  return $data;
}
```

Then when you call the function, your returned result can be used like this:

```
$uiD = 1;
$result = Profile_Pic($uiD);
$photo = $result['photo'];
$photo_small = $result['photo_small'];
```

Comment: This has worked. I don't understand why you received a -1. Why return it in an array instead of just pulling the data?

Comment: @iBrazilian - See my comments regarding using `fetchColumn()`.

Comment: FetchColumn doesn't seem to be working. I deleted the fetch inside the if parameters as it's already defined outside of it but it doesn't return the database info. Only loads the icons/users.png. Note: I tried both your original and without the fetch inside if.

Comment: @iBrazilian - I simplified my answer to simply check against the boolean value of `$row`. If there was no row returned, this should evalute to `FALSE`.